# Which type of function should I use?

Tags: c, function, types, linked-list

I have singly linked list with wchar_t string as data. If I want to add a new node and fill it with text, which type of function should I use?

I tried to use my linked list type, but I'm not sure if it's a good way. Could it be something like that?

```
typedef struct smth{
    wchar_t data;
    struct smth *next;
}smth;

smth* add_to_end(wchar_t *text, smth *head){
.
.
.
}
```

I decided to not input whole code, just as little as possible to show what I'm doing here and to ask how should it look like?

Comment: `wchar_t data;` it is not the string

Comment: If by "[w]hich type of function should I use" you mean what kind of arguments and their types as well as the return-type you should use, then that really depends on what you're function is supposed to do and how it does that. The question in its current form is simply to broad and unclear. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: If you are asking about the return type of the function, then it could be void, int, smth* or anything depending upon how to insert and what value you want to return after you have inserted. That value could be true or false that the insertion was successful or the head pointer of the linked list or the pointer to the last node you just inserted.

Comment: @VidorVistrom so void is ok if I only want to add a new node at the end and fill it with value, right?

Comment: Yes. That would do. There is no harm!

Comment: @VidorVistrom Except in the case when the list is empty and `head` is a null pointer and the OP assigns to `head` inside the function. Since the OP leaves out so many details it's really impossible to give some definitive answers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes the OP lacks information. That's why I wrote that the return type could be anything depending upon the use case. Of course if he returns null he has to check and make sure it is fail safe. The quality of question, no doubt, could be improved

Answer (score 1):

With this line: `wchar_t data;`, you can only store one wide character.

Regarding the function that you have shown `smth* add_to_end(wchar_t *text, smth *head)`:
No need to pass a pointer to `wchar_t` in this function, since in the node definition you intend to keep only a single wide character.

If you don't want to make the `head` pointer global, then I think you will need to pass new `head` everytime you are calling `add_to_end` alongwith the `data`. And then the this function is returning the updated `head`  of the linked list, which you can collect later somewhere in the code. This returned `smth*` will be the new head.

Inside the function, `add_to_end`, you may want to to something like this:

```
// Assuming prototype as smth* add_to_end(wchar_t text, smth *head)
struct tmp* = malloc(sizeof(struct));
if(tmp == NULL)
{
    printf("\nMemory allocation failed");
    return NULL;
}
tmp->data = text;
tmp->next = head;
head = tmp;
return tmp;
```